# можно ли использовать переменную spd как параметр style

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```
function sp(t){
    var spd = t.id;
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = document.getElementById(spd).value+"px";
    console.log(spd);
    poselemupr(); 
}
```

Можно ли использовать переменную `spd` как параметр `style`? Переменная возвращает id элемента, `id="width"`

Наподобие этого:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.spd = document.getElementById(spd).value+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(id).style[spd] = document.getElementById(spd).value+"px";
```